# how to embed a web page that has anti-embed javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I want to embed a web page into my own html with 'iframe'.
But I find that some web pages dont want themselves to be embeded. They have some anti-embed javascript code such as:

```
if(top !== self)

{

top.location.href = self.location.href;

}
```

how to embed these pages in my own html?

I try to change "top" to the iframe window in my html.

```
var ifr = document.frames ? document.frames("ifr_1") : 
document.getElementById("ifr_1").contentWindow;
window.top = ifr;
```

but it didn't work.

can anyone help me?

Comment: if they don't want you too, maybe they have their own reasons

Comment: plus if those iframes are on a different domain. you can't access their variables

Comment: yes, you are right. cannt access their variables. so maybe there is no way I can embed this kind of page? @lbu

Comment: I'm not sure it's ethical to embed if the owners do not want you too (except for personal use).  Anyway, Your server can fetch the page, and just forward the good parts.  Or, you can user a browser-extension, like Greasemonkey, to ajax-in the good parts.  (Extensions can get around the same-origin policy.)

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is not possible directly possible.

May be you could try using proxy to fetch the content and disable the script in the HTML code obtained using proxy. and display in your iframe. But it is not advisable.